# Using Bootstrap-select with icons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, icons

I want to create an icon drop-down box where I can display icons, their names, and then be able to search through them with Bootstrap select.

In my current state, I have solved both problems, but when Bootstrap-select is enabled the icons stop showing.

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
     <div class="select">
           <select class="selectpicker" id="iconpicker" data-live-search="true" style="font-family: premium-solid-icons">
           <option value="none" selected="" disabled="disabled">Ingen</option>
           <option value='psi-3d-glasses'>&#xe900; 3d Glasses</option>
           <option value='psi-3d-glasses2'>&#xe901; 3d Glasses2</option>
           </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

I am pretty clueless, but it seems like the Bootstrap-select overwrites the style of the select dropbox.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Hi rasmus, there is a new bootstrap select! https://github.com/mikeGHQ/IBootstrap#select

Answer (score 0):

I was right, the premium-solid-icons was being overridden by Bootstraps Select,so i had to include that font-family setting into the Bootstrap-Select.css file.

```
.bootstrap-select {
width: 220px \0; /*IE9 and below*/
font-family: premium-solid-icons;
(etc.)
```

Thank you for taking your time to read, and i hope this will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the **Custom Option Renderer** from **React Virtualized Select**

Get it from here:
`https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized-select/`

Demo: `https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized-select/`